# React JS - "npm start" does't work for the second time

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, runtime-error

I just started learning React JS and for some reason I can't start the program. Just to make things clear - I'm using VS Code, Mac OS with the latest installed versions of Node.js and nmp.

So, after I type for the first time "npx create-react-app my-app" -> "cd my-app" -> "npm start" everything works just fine, new window opens and I can manipulate react components as usual. But once I close the project and reopen it in VS Code, "npm start" shows this error when I try to run it again:

```
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mainuser/Desktop/React/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

I tried to just create new React project and close it without any changes. And even if I haven't changed anything inside - again, first time it works just fine but later I get the same error as mentioned above. What can be the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure you were in the directory of "my-app"? The log suggests that you were in "React".

Comment: seems like you are running  the command in wrong directory. Also npm install before running npm start.

Comment: Well, if by directory you mean inside the folder "my-app" in VS Code then yes, I was there when I tried to start the application. I have also tried to use "nmp install" as Pranay suggested but it keeps saying that "no such file or directory". May be I don't really understand the concept of directory itself? Before type "nmp install" or "npm start" I make sure to click on "my-app" first. Is that it or I'm missing something?

Comment: Also, after it shows this error, new file of package-lock.json with object {"lockfileVersion": 1} creates itself...

Comment: Ok, I played with it a little bit and yes indeed, after I moved "my-app" outside of the folder "React" and then pasted only "my-app" in VS Code it works fine. Can you please then tell me, how do I access my application if I put it in another sub folder? Or it can't have a paren't folder(like "React" in this case)?

Comment: You have to `cd my-app` in your command line just like you did the first time, the logs show that you were in the folder `.../Desktop/React/` which doesn't contain your app data. You might have had the directory open in VS Code, but you also need to be in that directory in your terminal as well.

Comment: The terminal in VS code should tell you your current directory or you can type `pwd` to know. Then, if you are not in your app directory ("my-app" in this case), you can use `cd` command to navigate. Learn more about the usage [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#File_.26_Directory_Commands).

Comment: Alright, got it, thank you so much for your answers guys!